# How to change just image file without creating new mediafile in the Wordpress?

Tags: image, wordpress

The problem is: **I upload some images to the Wordpress mediafiles and I need to change them to the new versions of it**. But I cant understand how to do that in administrator panel. There is no such option.

I find only two ways:

1. **Delete mediafile with image and create new**.

   - **Pro:**
     All things doing inside admin panel. Simple for unskilled users.
   - **Contra:** 
     A lot of unnecessary work: you need to copy descriptions and name and other stuff and built correct thumbnail etc.
2. **Change files directly throw FTP**.

   - **Pro:**
     You just change the file itself, no need to copypatsing a lot of stuff. Simple.
   - **Contra:**
     You need to rename file exactly as old version. You need to run FTP application. Not usefull for unskilled users.

But both is extremely bad. Can you show me more useful way to refresh image file in wordpress megiafiles? Some trick or some plugin? De jure I can add it to the admin template, but it looks like great bunch of work.
Thanks.

P. S. In fact my dad need in it and I try to find better and easiest way for him to do such basic thing.

Comment: why not you edit image ??

Comment: From what I remember, there's no way of doing this directly in WordPress. However, the [Enable Media Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/) plugin should do exactly what you need. You might find more answers asking on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ; this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. I try to check it.